# Deposit cash into my business from my wife's account?

Tags: united-states, small-business, limited-liability-company, deposits

I have a LLC (let's call it XYZ, LLC) and I am the sole owner and I am going to use the money of the company to buy some assets. However, XYZ doesn't have enough capital to make the purchase.

My wife has some spare cash in her personal account and she said I can use her money for now. Can I deposit her money into my business without paying interest?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. [By US law](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1041), (and barring any prenuptial agreements specifying otherwise), your spouse's money is also your money, so you can deposit *your* money into the business account which should just increase your company basis. How you work out paying your wife back is between you and her, but does not need to involve the company if you don't want it to.

Comment: This is exact answer I am looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just be careful that you actually run your LLC as a separate entity and properly keep its funds separated from personal funds. Otherwise, the LLC may not provide you protection from liability.